# Is it possible to improve the performance of ruby application using Ruby Socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets

I have an application and i want to improve the performance of that application.
For which i am trying to use Ruby Socket, so that whenever the data in the database changes respective page will get change automatically.

I just want confirmation that this is possible or not and if it is possible some demo application which uses the Ruby Socket.

If it is not possible using Ruby Socket, what are the other ways using which 
i can improve the loading time of the pages of my application.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the ways to improve application performance, using a Ruby socket seems like kind of a last ditch approach. Improving performance really depends on where the bottlenecks are, so I would start by figuring out exactly where you have issues. I'd recommend [New Relic](https://newrelic.com) for this, and you can even use a [free local dev mode version](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode) if it's not in your budget. Is your database not responding fast enough? Is your Ruby code doing too much in a request? Does your server need more resources (memory, cpu, etc)? Once you figure out where you have performance problems, then you can target each issue directly.

Comment: I guess he means not performance, but async receiving of data changes ("...so that whenever the data in the database changes respective page will get change automatically..."). This indeed can be done with sockets or long polling or whatever.